# Is Apple using black magic to accomplish camera's preview orientation?

Tags: ios, iphone, camera, avfoundation

I have this AVFoundation camera app of mine. The camera preview is the result of a filter, applied by didOutputSampleBuffer method.

When I setup the camera I am following what apple did on one of their sample codes ([CIFunHouse](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/CIFunHouse/Listings/CIFunHouse_FilterListController_h.html)):

```
  // setting up the camera 
  CGRect bounds = [self.containerOpenGL bounds];

  _eaglContext = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES3];

  _videoPreviewView = [[GLKView alloc] initWithFrame:bounds
                                             context:_eaglContext];

  [self.containerOpenGL addSubview:_videoPreviewView];
  [self.containerOpenGL sendSubviewToBack:_videoPreviewView];

  id<MTLDevice> device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice();

  NSDictionary *options = @{kCIContextUseSoftwareRenderer : @(NO),
                            kCIContextPriorityRequestLow : @(YES),
                            kCIContextWorkingColorSpace : [NSNull null]};

  _ciContext = [CIContext contextWithEAGLContext:_eaglContext options:options];

  [_videoPreviewView bindDrawable];
  _videoPreviewViewBounds = CGRectZero;
  _videoPreviewViewBounds.size.width = _videoPreviewView.drawableWidth;
  _videoPreviewViewBounds.size.height = _videoPreviewView.drawableHeight;

  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);

    _videoPreviewView.transform = transform; 
    _videoPreviewView.frame = bounds;

  });
```

`self.containerOpenGL` is a full screen view and is constrained to the four corners of the screen. Autorotation is on.

But this is the problem...

When I setup the `GLKView` and `self.ciContext` it is created assuming the device is on a particular orientation. If the device is on a particular orientation and I run the application, the `previewView` will fit the entire `self.containerOpenGL` area but when I rotate the device the `previewView` will be out center.

I see that Apple code works perfectly and they don't use any constraints. They do not use any autorotation method, no `didLayoutSubviews` and when you rotate the device, running their code, everything rotates except the preview view. And worse than that, my `previewView` appears to rotate but not their's.

Is this black magic? How do I they do that?

Comment: Are they using autoresizing of flexible width and height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They add their preview view to a uiwindow and that is why it does not rotate. I hope this answers the question. If not I will continue to look through their source code.

Quote from source code.

> we make our video preview view a subview of the window, and send it to the back; this makes `FHViewController`'s view (and its UI elements) on top of the video preview, and also makes video preview unaffected by device rotation

They also add this

```
_videoPreviewView.enableSetNeedsDisplay = NO;
```

This may keep it from responding as well

Edit: It appears that now the preview rotates and the UI does as well so to combat this you can add a second window and send it to the back and make the main window clear and add the previewView to the second window with a dummyViewController that tells it not to autorotate by overriding the appropriate method.  This will allow the preview to not rotate but the UI to rotate.

Comment: YOU ARE RIGHT SIR! I have not noticed that! THANKS!

Comment: strangely I added my previewView to the window and it still rotates... :(

Comment: Do you also have it someway reference in the viewcontroller. Maybe set the autoresizing on the preview view to flexible height and width

Comment: nope. still rotating. Another strange thing is that Apple casts `UIView *` to the `window` variable when they get it from the delegate...

Comment: Are you doing this in storyboard? And are they doing it in storyboard?  Are they supporting all interfaces in the test project. If the root view is set on your window then it will rotate according to that rootviewcontroller

Comment: yes I am doing this on storyboard. They are also doing it in storyboard (or at least they have a storyboard there). What do you mean by "if the root view is set on your window"?

Comment: OK give me a bit and I will open their project and break it to figure out what it is making it work

Comment: Is it the rotation animation that you want to get rid of.  Which problem are we trying to solve.  The sample code does not stay full screen for me.  I can tell you how to stop the animation on rotation but I am trying to find out what the question is

Comment: I want the camera preview not to autorotate and I want all the rest to rotate. If you have an iPad you can see that in action. Run iPad's native camera app. Rotate the device. You will see that the preview does not rotate but the controls do.

Comment: I have created a video to demonstrate... http://www.filedropper.com/img2956x   notice how the preview is not rotating but the controls are.

Comment: I have created an independent question out of this. If you want to answer there...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42752361/how-to-create-an-app-using-the-single-view-app-template-where-the-main-window-do

Comment: Yep I think that adding that question is good.  Does it rotate when you run it on an iPhone.  Mine does. I don't have an iPad handy to test. I think they are showing a separate controller for the iPad to make it look like it rotates.  They are dismissing in willRotate and presenting again in didrotate specifically for iPad.  I am curious to know what it is like on the phone for you

Comment: What iOS version do you have on that iPad?

Comment: 10.2.1 but the app is compiled for 9.3. No, in fact I think apple is doing what they do on their CIFunHouse sample code. The preview is not rotating at all and the controls are. There are clearly two hierarchies there. I will test the solution you have posted on the other question. thanks.

Comment: Did you see the answer to your other question?  It works perfect for not rotating the preview but allowing everything else to rotate

Comment: not working for me for some reason... I am investigating

Comment: The controller of the second window has to have autorotate method returning no and that is where the preview gets added. The second window.

Comment: You don't event really need the controller for anything else on the second window but to return no and be the rootview of the second window