# How to create an App using the Single View App template where the main window does not rotate but the rest does?

Tags: ios, camera, avfoundation, uiwindow, autorotate

How to create an App using the Single View App template where the main window does not rotate but its rootViewController and everything else autorotates?

Apple does that on [CIFunHouse](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/CIFunHouse/Listings/CIFunHouse_FilterListController_h.html) but because the code is poorly explained in that matter, it is impossible to know how they did it. If you run the app you will see that the camera's preview window does not autorotate because the preview was added to the window but everything else does.

Apple uses this technique on their native iPad camera app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer is not clean but I can give you a fix. At some point the main application window must not have autorotated like it does now but at some point it started rotating according to the rootviewcontroller. At least this source code suggests that. I started developing at the end of iOS 6 and I think this source was written about that time.  The best fix I could find for allowing everything to rotate in the example for me but having the preview to not rotate was to add a second window.  Set the main window background to clear.  Then add the previewLayer to the second window behind the main window.  In code it would look like this.

The AppDelegate looked like this.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreMotion/CoreMotion.h>

@interface FHAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
{
@private
  CMMotionManager *_motionManager;
}
@property (strong, readonly, nonatomic) CMMotionManager *motionManager;
//future preview window
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *previewWindow;
@property (assign, readonly, nonatomic) UIDeviceOrientation realDeviceOrientation;

@end
```

Then in the viewDidLoad of the FHViewController instead of adding to the main window I did this and it added where they get the main window I add the previewView to that.

```
   // we make our video preview view a subview of the window, and send it to the back; this makes FHViewController's view (and its UI elements) on top of the video preview, and also makes video preview unaffected by device rotation
   //nothing special about this viewcontorller except it has
   //-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
   //return NO;
   //}

    TestViewController *test = [[TestViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"TestViewController" bundle:nil];
    FHAppDelegate *delegate = ((FHAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate);
    delegate.previewWindow = [[UIWindow alloc]initWithFrame:window.bounds];
    UIWindow *previewWindow = delegate.previewWindow;
    [window setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    previewWindow.rootViewController = test;
    previewWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelNormal - 1;

    [previewWindow setBounds:delegate.window.bounds];

    [previewWindow makeKeyAndVisible];
    [previewWindow addSubview:_videoPreviewView];
    [previewWindow sendSubviewToBack:_videoPreviewView];
```

Because the previewWindow has to have a rootviewcontroller and it determines the rotation you can see my testviewcontroller has autorotate of NO.  Hope this helps.  It is working for me on iOS 10.

Edit: The view in the example above does not rotate but the window animation on rotation is bad visually.  It can be removed by overriding 
willTransitionToSize

```
    [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
```

and after completion

```
[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];
```

See swift version on [GitHub](https://github.com/agibson73/TestSingleViewNoRotate)

For an iPad requires Full Screen must be check.

Comment: this is not working for me. Do you have a project you can send me? I will have to leave now and will return later to answer you. thanks

Comment: Hi, I have tested that out but unfortunately the yellow window of your project that is not supposed to rotate is in fact rotating...

Comment: The subviews are not rotating.  The container inside the window rotates.  What is your desired outcome.  Do you just not want to see the container rotate or do you want the subviews to rotate.  You can see clearly the label does not rotate the label top will be whatever way you rotate the device

Comment: like CIFunHouse and the iPad Camera, I want the full screen view NOT to rotate, because this will be the camera preview. The other stuff can rotate. Apple gets this behavior using a lunacy method that they never explained but works by black magic, that is "assigning the non rotating view to the window" because in their delirious view, the window descendants will not rotate, what works by miracle.

Comment: Well CIFunHouse does not do that for me so I don't know what version you compiled on.  Mine clips subviews and rotates them as well.

Comment: I think during the transition now meaning current API a container view is added that handles the transition. I have tried setting that container to clear remove clips and layer masks. I do know the container does not contain the window that does not rotate. But either it is masking the layer below which is our nonrotating window or it is covering it up.

Comment: honestly the only thing I have not tried is placing the non-rotating window inside the container and rotating it the exact opposite direction

Comment: Updated the github again. Check it out

Comment: sorry. The yellow controller is still rotating for me. Please [watch this video](http://www.filedropper.com/img2956x) that I did to demonstrate Apple doing what I need. Look at the full screen camera preview. It keeps attached to the 4 corners and did not rotate but the buttons do.

Comment: so to fix that on an iPad go back to my project go to settings and check requires full screen.  I have been testing on an iPhone but I am updating the GitHub

Comment: AHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH **NOW WE ARE TALKING!!!** Please update the answer with the correct stuff so I can accept it. I cannot update you enough!!!!! thanks

Comment: Glad it helped. Funny you were testing on an iPad the whole time and I was testing on an iPhone

Comment: I am looking at your code but I don't understand it. It works but I don't understand how. Can you change this answer to explain how? thanks

Comment: It makes a second window that does not rotate. Windows now follow the rotation of the view controller. I don't think they did in the past. The no rotate view controller could have a property called nonrotating window instead of it being in the app delegate. That's probably where I should've declared it. The part about disabling the animations keeps the window from showing the rotating containers that makes it look like it rotated when it really never rotates. The other window however is rotating.

Comment: simply brilliant. it is everything working perfectly now! THANKS! +1 to the question and all your comments! 

Answer (score 0):

With using navigation controller you can create an Objective-C category like and use these in sub viewcontrollers

```
#import "UINavigationController+Orientation.h"

@implementation UINavigationController (Orientation)

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return [self.topViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}

@end
```

For Swift

```
extension UINavigationController {

    open override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return topViewController?.supportedInterfaceOrientations ?? .portrait
    }

    open override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
        return true
    }

}
```